# Dplyr - Mutate dynamically named variables using other dynamically named variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a new column with a dynamically created name and populate the field with an expression involving other dynamically created variables. For instance, consider the below data frame.

```
ID    multiplier    value1_2015    value2_2015    value1_2016    value2_2016
 1           0.5              2              3              1              4
 2           1.0              2              4              5              1
```

I want to write a function which is given the data frame, and a year and then evaluates an expression for only the corresponding year variables, and stores the result in a column called `total_year`, where `year` is the value given to the function. For instance, if the expression was

`multiplier * value1_year + value2_year` and I called `my_fun(df, 2016)` I should receive

```
ID multiplier value1_2015 value2_2015 value1_2016 value2_2016  total_2016
 1        0.5           2           3           1           4         4.5
 2        1.0           2           4           4           5           9
```

Here is what I have

```
my_fun <- function(df, year) {

 year <- enquo(year)

 total_header <- paste("total", quo_name(year), sep = "_")
 calc1_header <- paste("value1", quo_name(year), sep = "_")
 calc2_header <- paste("value2", quo_name(year), sep = "_")

 calc1_header <- enquo(calc1_header)
 calc2_header <- enquo(calc2_header)

 ret_table <- df %>%
 mutate(!!total_header := multiplier * !!calc1_header + !!calc2_header)

 return(ret_table)

}
```

When I try this I get the following `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.`

Replacing the expression with something like just `!!total_header := !!calc1_header` runs with no error, produces the correct column name, but the values in the column are the string "value1_2016", not the respective values from the column named `value1_2016`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `sym` rather than `enquo` for `calc1_header`, etc?

Comment: You don't need the `enquo/quo_name` at all here because 'year' is numeric and make sure to use the braces `mutate(!!total_header := multiplier * (!!calc1_header) + (!!calc2_header))` after doing `calc1_header <- rlang::sym(calc1_header)` and `calc2_header`

Comment: There we go, replacing `enquo` with `rlang::sym` for `calc1_header` and `calc2_header` worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here, we don't need the `enquo/quo_name` for 'year' as we are passing a numeric value.  The output of `paste` will be `character` class, using `sym` from `rlang` (as @joran mentioned) this can be converted to symbol and evaluated with `!!`.  Make sure to add braces around the '!! calc1_header' and '!! calc2_header' to evaluate the specific object

```
my_fun <- function(df, year) {

  total_header <- paste("total", year, sep = "_")
  calc1_header <- rlang::sym(paste("value1", year, sep = "_"))
  calc2_header <- rlang::sym(paste("value2", year, sep = "_"))

 df %>%
       mutate(!!total_header := multiplier * (!!calc1_header) + (!!calc2_header))



}

my_fun(df1, 2016)
#   ID multiplier value1_2015 value2_2015 value1_2016 value2_2016 total_2016
#1  1        0.5           2           3           1           4        4.5
#2  2        1.0           2           4           4           5        9.0
```

Comment: The braces around `!!var` are not needed anymore since `rlang` v0.2.0.

Comment: @slhck  I noticed it earlier, but I  kept it to assume that as a separate block