# piping dplyr mutate with unknown variable name

Tags: r, dplyr, piping

I'm trying to use `mutate` from `dplyr` with dynamic variables names.  I've found a couple of post on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005419/dplyr-without-hard-coding-the-variable-names), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440812/dplyr-mutate-dynamically-named-variables-using-other-dynamically-named-variabl)) which got me closer but not to a workable solution.  I don't think much is missing, but I require your help for it.

Here is a reproducible example very similar to my problem.  I have tables that have 2 fields, one of them called either `AD` or any other name.   This field as to be a factor, but could be character or integer.  My function need to convert to factor.

```
library(dplyr)

t1 <- data.frame(f1 = 1:4, AD = 1:4)
t2 <- data.frame(f1 = 1:4, FC = 1:4)

ff <- function(tt){

  # find the variable name
  if(any(colnames(tt)=="AD")){
    vv <- quo(AD)
  } else {
    vv <- colnames(tt) %>% .[.!="f1"]
    vv <- enquo(vv)
  }

  # make the mutate
  tt %>% mutate(!!quo_name(vv) := as.factor(!!vv))      
}
```

With the help of the link cited earlier, I manage to make the function work for table that have `AD` (using the `quo`, `!!` and `:=` which were function I didn't know about before).

```
ff(tt=t1) %>% str
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ f1: int  1 2 3 4
 $ AD: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 2 3 4
```

This works well.  but when I send a table with an unknown variable name:

```
ff(tt=t2) %>% str
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ f1: int  1 2 3 4
 $ FC: Factor w/ 1 level "FC": 1 1 1 1
```

My `FC` is now wrong with only 1 factor being `FC`

I think the problem is in the way I set `vv` in the second option which give me the wrong `env` value:

```
quo(AD)
<quosure>
  expr: ^AD
  env:  global


vv <- colnames(tt) %>% .[.!="f1"]
enquo(vv)
<quosure>
  expr: ^"FC"
  env:  empty
```

Any idea how to fix my problem?  I open to base R solution, however it as to be able to fit in a long piping procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `enquo` there. That's for turning a value passed as a parameter into a quosure. Instead you need to turn a string into a symbol. For that you can use `as.name()` or `rlang::sym()`

```
ff <- function(tt){

  # find the variable name
  if(any(colnames(tt)=="AD")){
    vv <- quo(AD)
  } else {
    vv <- colnames(tt) %>% .[.!="f1"]
    vv <- as.name(vv)
  }

  # make the mutate
  tt %>% mutate(!!quo_name(vv) := as.factor(!!vv))      
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it also seems I could use `as.name` in the `AD` part: `    vv <- as.name("AD")`  Why does `quo`exist then, should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: `quo()` creates a quosure which captures not only an expression/symbol but also an environment. In this particular case, you're not really interested in capturing an environment since you just want to evaluate a symbol in the context of the data in the mutate chain. If you had a more complicated expression than just a column name, you'd have to use something fancier than `as.name()`.